# ANGULAR - How to center align mat-hint or label in div with radio-group - ANGULAR

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i align vertically in the center one mat-hint or label inside one div with mat-radio-group?

Today, my code has this sequency:

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%">
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="30%">
            <mat-hint>{{ 'É bivolt?' | translate: moduleName }}</mat-hint>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="70%">
            <mat-radio-group id="rgpStaAparelhoBivoltNewUcServicoRessarcDanoEquipEletr"
              [(ngModel)]="newUcServicoRessarcDanoEquipEletr.staAparelhoBivolt" [disabled]="staViewing">
              <mat-radio-button value="S">{{ 'Sim' | translate: moduleName }}</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="N">{{ 'Não' | translate: moduleName }}</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="D">{{ 'Não sei' | translate: moduleName }}</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I'ld like to align the mat-hint in the same row of the values from the mat-radio-group without css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the align problem with the following code:

```
style="margin: auto;"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the component css file add the following class:

```
.centered {
   text-align: center;
}
```

and update mat-hint code:

```
<mat-hint class="centered">{{ 'É bivolt?' | translate: moduleName }}</mat-hint>
```

Comment: Element inline css is not an option too?

Comment: The css proposed didn't worked. We're using generic class css in the system so, the css isn't the best option

Comment: Solved with style="margin: auto". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this just add a class **justifyline**

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container">
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%">
        <div fxLayout="row" class="justifyline">
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="30%">
            <mat-hint>1</mat-hint>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="70%">
            <mat-radio-group id="rgpStaAparelhoBivoltNewUcServicoRessarcDanoEquipEletr"
              [(ngModel)]="newUcServicoRessarcDanoEquipEletr.staAparelhoBivolt" [disabled]="staViewing">
              <mat-radio-button value="S">1</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="N">2</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="D">3</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.justifyline mat-hint{float:left;}
```

Comment: Works fine with specifc class but in this project we're using generic css class and the parent class was killing the following class.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the container try:

```html
style = "margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;
```

Comment: Solved with style="margin: auto". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, I 'm glad you solved it. Sometimes it only works with left right margins, sometimes with all of them like you did, it depends on parent tags for the most part, `margin: 0 auto` sometimes is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="center-label">
...
</mat-form-field>
```

In CSS:

```
mat-form-field.center-label label {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'm not sure if hints are placed inside a label as well but I doubt it.

If you're trying to do it with the hint, then inspect the mat-form-field and find which element your hint text is located in. Then you just need to specify that element in your css (you may need to include some constant class name that angular adds in the css selector which may change depending on the angular version).